Is the penalty method also used for non-convex constrained optimization?
Right now I am dealing with penalty methods for constrained optimization. According to my lecture notes part of such penalty method is the repeated solving of a subproblem of the following form:
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}P_{a_k}(x)$$
$P_{a_k}(x) = f(x) + a_k*p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is some function penalizing $x$ when it is not feasible.
According to my lecture notes the upper problem has to be solved and so you need a GLOBAL solution. If $f$ is not a convex function solving this problem globally could be very hard or not? Are penalty methods even used if $f$ is not convex?
